# Invertible elements in the number line $R$

Tags: linear-algebra, synthetic-differential-geometry

In SDG the geometric line is described by the number line $R$ which is a not a field, but a ring: this implies some of its elements are not invertible. One of the key idea is the set $D=[x:x^2=0]$ where $x$ is not necessarily zero. My question is, are these $x\in D$ the only elements $\in R$ which are not invertible?

Comment: Are you talking about the ring $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$?

Comment: For what I'm understanding (no much), in SDG the geometric line: the physical line you draw on a plane, is described by the so called 'number line' $R$ and not by the real line $\mathbb {R}$. So there is no $\mathbb{R}$ to begin with, and therefore I'm not sure the symbol $\mathbb{R}[x]/(x^2)$ has a meaning in SDG. My questions is for $x\in R$ (not $\mathbb{R}$) to be also $\in D$ (which means $x^2=0$), does this $x$ has to be necessarily not invertible?

Comment: the only choice that makes x not invertible would be 0, so that’s not very productive. Based on the wiki article, I think the dual numbers are the ring of interest.

Comment: From M. Shulman paper on [SDG](https://home.sandiego.edu/~shulman/papers/sdg-pizza-seminar.pdf), pag 5. "Since our nilsquare infinitesimals are not invertible, they are not nonzero. But this does not necessarily imply they are equal to zero." He seems to say that those $x\in D$ are nilsquare infinitesimals, not invertible and not equal to zero. I just found our this today...

Comment: Wow, what a confusing paper. I can't believe this guy contributes to the stuff he says he contributes to on his site! He is working in some constructivist setting that I guess I have no idea about the nuances of.  Do you have another question?

Comment: SDG is quite off mainstream but its motivations dated back to the Greek geometers. For example Protagoras was arguing against Euclid that the intersection of a curve to its tangent line happens not just at a single point but over an infinitesimal interval. That interval is indeed this $D$ considered in  SDG. No other question, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

The invertible elements of the dual numbers $\mathbb R[x]/(x^2)$ are exactly things whose representatives have nonzero constant term.

Everything has a representative that looks like $\alpha +\beta x +(x^2)$, so the invertible elements are exactly the things with $\alpha \neq 0$.